# Android Asynctask calling server API

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to know about `asynctask`, suppose I have 5-6 server **api** now I want to get response from each **api** but condition is that I just want to use a single `asynctask`.

Now just having a single `Asynctask` but execution is not done properly.

```
private class HttpAsynctaskinvitatioal extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {



        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();



        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {


            return POST(urls[0]);
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            invitatioalurl=result.trim();


        }
    }
```

Comment: You can hit on one URL and get response from it. Now check that the response is according to your expectation. If yes, then hit on next URL and again check your response with your expectation and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `AsyncClass` like as follows:

```
public class BackgroundNetwork extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    Context context;
    ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progress.setTitle("Loading...");
        progress.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    public BackgroundNetwork(Context activity) {
        context = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (progress.isShowing()) {
            progress.dismiss();
        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Then you can call this class as follows:

```
new BackgroundNetwork(Activity.this){
     protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

       String result = params[0];

        //call api here or any background work you want to execute

       return result;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);  //this is a important line to add.

        //get your response result here then do UI changes whatever you want to do.
      }


 }.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be done from your technical logics. Just call single asynctask but in different manner to get response of each url.

Answer (score 0):

Pass different urls as parameters.

or

set it in the Construct fuction.